# How to add vertical space struts after hline?

Tags: spacing, longtable, supertabular

I know the table trick of adding "struts" in the first line after and the last line before a `\hline`. I use it throughout my document, and it looks good that way.

However, now I am working within a `longtable` / `supertabular` environment. If a page break is reached, these environments add a running head, which in my case ends with a `\hline`.

Now I've got a problem. While the `longtable` / `supertabular` environment knows where a page break happens, and adds the new header, *I* don't know that. I cannot add the "above" strut at the appropriate place.

The only option that I see is adding a "below" strut to the head's `\hline`. But I don't know how to do that...?!?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
 \hline
 \noalign{\vskip 3in}
```

puts some space after the line.

Comment: Could you make your answers a bit longer? The software flags them as "low quality posts" for review. `:-)`

Comment: I could change the 3in to 4in, if that would help:-)

Comment: Similar to the `booktabs` solution, this breaks vertical lines...

Comment: Basically it is the booktabs solution, if you look what booktabs does internally. If you have vertical lines then put a strut with big depth in the row before the line. that extends the rules, then use `\noalign{\vskip-3pt}\hline\noalign{\skip3pt}` to move the rule back over the extended line.

Comment: Nice... but since the only vertical lines in that particular table are on the outside, I already worked around that by replacing those outer lines with a `mbframed` environment. ;-)

Comment: Some (much) later change broke the `mdframed` solution for me, and I came to realize the trick you mentioned in your March 1st comment has some charme of its own. ;-)

Comment: The comment from Mar 1, '12 has `\noalign{\skip3pt}` which for me breaks with `! Missing number, treated as zero.`; `\noalign{\vskip3pt}` seems to pass

Comment: @sdaau sorry, it should be vskip as you note.

Answer (score 6):

The following is *not* a direct answer to your question but, instead, a suggestion to consider taking a different and (in my view) ultimately much simpler approach to solving your problem.

Like you do now, I also used to place struts above and below various `\hline` instructions to improve the overall look of a `tabular` (or `tabular*`, `supertabular`, etc.) environment. I think I first started using struts in this fashion after reading an article by Claudio Beccari entitled "Correct spacing for tables and arrays," published in *TeX and TUG News*, Vol 2, No 3, 1993. (This article is available online; see pp. 10-11 in, e.g., http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/info/digests/ttn/ttn2n3.pdf. I think it's still well worth a read.)

Then, just a few years ago, I "discovered" the [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs) package, which takes the *opposite* approach to solving the problem of obtaining proper spacing around horizontal lines in tables. Instead of changing the depths/heights (by inserting the appropriate struts) of the lines of text immediately before/after an `\hline`, the package provides the commands `\toprule`, `\bottomrule`, `\midrule`, and `\cmidrule`: these automatically insert an appropriate amount of vertical whitespace below and/or above the respective horizontal lines. (In addition, these horizontal lines tend to look much more professional because they don't all have the same width, but that's a separate issue.)

Suppose, then, that you need to create an extra-long table that contains three columns, and suppose that you're going to use the `xtabular` environment -- made available by loading the [xtab](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xtab) package -- to create this table. You could then set up something like this:

```
\tablefirsthead{%  % for table header on first page
\toprule
  Col 1 header & Col 2 header & Col 3 header \\
\midrule
}

\tablehead{%     % for table headers except on first page
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\small\emph{Continued from previous page}} \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]  % line with same width as \toprule but with more spacing
  Col 1 header & Col 2 header & Col 3 header \\
\midrule
}

\tabletail{%    % for table tails except on very last page
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]  %line with same width as \bottomrule but with more spacing
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\small\emph{Continued on next page}} \\
}

\tablelasttail{\bottomrule}  % table tail on very last page

\tablecaption{A very long table} \label{tab:verylong}
\begin{xtabular}{lcc}
% various lines
\midrule
% various lines
\midrule
% various lines
% ...
\end{xtabular}
```

What makes this approach, in my view, so appealing is that you've delegated to LaTeX and, in particular, the macros of `booktabs` package all work related to setting the appropriate vertical whitespace around the various horizontal lines. No need for you (the author) to figure out where to insert struts.

Comment: That, indeed, seems to be the solution. Unfortunately `booktabs` breaks vertical lines... (I know they are a "no-no" typographically, but sometimes there *are* good reasons for using them...)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks so much for your edits!