# Inserting a small vertical space in a table

Tags: tables, spacing, positioning

Is there a way that I can insert a small space in a table? 
When I use a superscript, the number touches the `\hline`.

```
\documentclass[9pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(0,0)

\put(20,-136){\mbox{    
        \footnotesize   
        \begin{tabular}{ p{8em}  r  r  l }  
        \hline      
                        & Total     & Average   & Unit   \\
        \hline      
        Area1           & 419773    &   9.15        &  \emph{m$^2$}      \\      
        Area2           & 0     &   0       &  \emph{m$^3$}      \\
        \hline  
        \end{tabular}
    }}  

\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

I tried inserting `\vspace` but this does not move everything, just one cell.

```
\vspace{0.001 in} Area1 & \vspace{0.001 in} 419773  &   \vspace{0.001 in} 9.15      & \vspace{0.001 in} \emph{m$^2$} \
```

My preference would be to adjust this without an external package, as I am using an old version of LaTeX on a server that I cannot replace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Column padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-padding-in-tables)

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50332/vertical-spacing-of-a-table-cell -- there are some good answers here also. Amusingly, the two questions were posted three hours apart.

Comment: 3 hours and 4 minutes!

Comment: See this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400425/70067 which also addressed a case I encountered that was not handled by the answers here.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

use

```
\rule{0pt}{4ex}
```

in the first column of that line.

Comment: This does work (thank you). It creates a small offset unless the cell contents are touching the code (no whitespace).

Comment: Ignore my previous message, this worked for me. +1

Comment: Can you please explain the arguments?

Comment: @NagabhushanSN as far as I understand, it's creating a horizontal line of length 0 above your cell's text (doesn't show up because it can't stretch to the right, but takes up the space anyway). The ```0pt``` is the length to the right, the ```4ex``` is the height (```4ex``` is 4 times the height of a lowercase x, so you can make it thinner by changing that 4).

Comment: Update: it's to the left of your cell's text, not above (the horizontal line height starts at the same baseline as the text).

Comment: btw, you can add space *under* the text by changing the ```\\``` ending to ```\\[4ex]```

Comment: Completely novel workaround!

Answer (score 61):

For a general reference on how to improve the spacing in `tabular` and `array` lines, see the article "Correct spacing for tables and arrays" by Claudio Beccari on p. 10 of [*TeX and TUG News* 1993 (Vol. 2, No. 3)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/digests/ttn/ttn2n3.pdf).

His method, which involves judiciously inserting "struts", applies to lines in `tabular` (as well as `tabular*`, `supertabular`, `xtabular`, `longtable`) and `array` environments which contain

- superscript material, on a line that's preceded by an `\hline`,
- subscript material, on a line that's followed by an `\hline`, and
- any other lines with material (including `\hline`s) above or below them that might result in a cramped look of the output.

He suggested defining a "top strut" and a "bottom strut" as follows:

```
\newcommand\T{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}       % Top strut
\newcommand\B{\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % Bottom strut
```

Using your MWE as a starting point -- by the way, `9pt` is *not* a recognized option in the `article` document class, so I'm omitting it -- one could put these macros to use as follows:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newcommand\T{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}       % Top strut
\newcommand\B{\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % Bottom strut

\begin{document}  
\begin{tabular}{ p{8em}  r  r  l }  
\hline      
          & Total     & Average   & Unit \T\B  \\    \hline      
Area 1    & 419773    &   9.15    &  m\textsuperscript{2} \T \\      
Volume 1  & 0         &      0    &  m\textsuperscript{3} \B \\    \hline  
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very nice approach. Is there a particular reason for putting the struts at the end of the line? That does add a very small padding for me (or maybe I am doing it wrong?)

Comment: @Boris - the struts can be inserted anywhere in a given row; I simply find it easiest to read the code if they're inserted at the start of the left-most cell or the end of right-most cell. There should be no extra (horizontal) padding from the struts; what you observe on the MWE is LateX's insertion of whitespace in the amount of `\tabcolsep`.

Comment: +1 for bottom strut.  why is the syntax different?

Comment: @flies - Thanks. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the syntax being different. Are you referring to the way the macros `\T` and `\B` are defined? A LaTeX `\rule` has one optional argument -- its depth, given in square brackets; a non-negative length parameter that indicates how much it protrudes below the baseline; if not provided, the default value of `0pt` is used -- and two mandatory arguments: the rule's width (`0pt` in both cases since we're creating "invisible" rules) and the rule's height above the baseline. The height is nonzero for a top strut and zero for a bottom strut.

Comment: I was asking about the square brackets in ignorance of the difference between depth and height.  It looks like my question is also answered in the latex wikibook: part 1 http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Rules_and_Struts part 2 http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#TeX_character_boxes

Comment: It's worth noting that if this appears with \frac or similar commands, then the \T and \B will need to go into the numerator part of \frac or the denominator.

Comment: @Joel - Thanks. The top and bottom struts defined in my answer are definitely set up with a working assumption that they'll be employed in a line of text (with uppercase and lowercase letters). If one has a  `\frac` or (worse!) `\dfrac` term in a given row, it'll definitely be essential to place the top- and bottom-struts in the numerator and denominator parts, respectively. :-)

Answer (score 21):

The simplest solution was given by David Carlisle in [How to add vertical space struts after hline?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46294/how-to-add-vertical-space-struts-after-hline)

```
\hline
\noalign{\vskip 2mm}
```

For those who can use the [`bigstrut`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bigstrut?lang=en) package, then just inserting `\bigstrut[t]` will fix the problem.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(0,0)

\put(20,-136){\mbox{    
        \footnotesize   
        \begin{tabular}{ p{8em}  r  r  l }  
        \hline      
                        & Total     & Average   & Unit   \\
        \hline      
        Area1           & 419773    &   9.15        &  \emph{m$^2$} \bigstrut[t]     \\  
        Area2           & 0     &   0       &  \emph{m$^3$}      \\
        \hline  
        \end{tabular}
    }}  

\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15):

you can load `array` package then

```
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
```

the array package is a required part of the core latex distribution, so will be available on all installations.

Answer (score 12):

use

```
    \addlinespace[2ex]
```

in the beginning of a line.

Of the [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package (which you want to use anyway to polish up your tables).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Could you please show how to use this in the MWE code that the question contains. It would be easier to understand for everybody what exactly to do, and also easier to check how the result looks like :) Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! This is the only solution that worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

fwiw, https://texfaq.org/FAQ-struttab summarises all the above, and mentions a couple of other packages.  (apologies for intruding with an obvious pointer.)

Comment: Broken link. Use a [web-archive](https://help.archive.org/hc/en-us/articles/360004651732-Using-The-Wayback-Machine) link.

Answer (score 3):

David's answer, [made relevant by Scott Prahl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50408/214194), is the winner for no-dependency simplicity. Because I don't want to control the spacing, I like [Christian's similar answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/591620/214194), which becomes:

```latex
\hline \noalign{\smallskip}
```

In some cases this looks better:

```latex
\noalign{\smallskip} \hline \noalign{\smallskip}
```

Either of which can be stored in a command:

```latex
\newcommand{\eqline}{\noalign{\smallskip} \hline \noalign{\smallskip}}
```

---

Explanation of why `\noalign{}` is needed welcome!

Comment: This helped me with [adding a horizontal line to an equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/635159/214194).

Comment: This seems better-suited as a comment as you're merely taking content from existing answers and elaborating on them. Would you agree?

Comment: Yea I'd agree, and went to do that first, but the space and formatting limitations of the comment don't support it as well.

Comment: Also, similar to Scott's answer, my answer comes from a post outside this thread.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worthwhile to take a look at the "booktabs" package, 
http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs. Then, using e.g. the command \midrule instead of \hline provides additional space between the columns.

Answer (score 1):

It’s easy to set `rowsep` with `tblr` environment of the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass[9pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\SetTblrInner{rowsep=2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(20,-136){\mbox{    
        \footnotesize   
        \begin{tblr}{ p{8em}  r  r  l }  
        \hline      
                        & Total     & Average   & Unit   \\
        \hline      
        Area1           & 419773    &   9.15        &  \emph{m$^2$}      \\      
        Area2           & 0     &   0       &  \emph{m$^3$}      \\
        \hline  
        \end{tblr}
    }}  
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a cool solution for putting spaces inside a table.  Simply add a row containing \vspace{-0.3cm}\.  This will add a row to the table and then back up the spacing by 0.3cm or whatever you want.

Answer (score -3):

`\rule{0pt}{4ex}}
  x&x\\
\;x&x\\
\;x&x\\`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Could you explain a bit more your answer?

Comment: It's not clear to me how this goes beyond Herbert's answer and what the `} x&x\ \;x&x\ \;x&x\` will achieve, it looks like this has an unmatched `}` which could cause trouble.