# fractions in table

Tags: tables, math-mode, fractions

I have a table with three columns, in the second and third sometimes appear fractions:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\begin{document}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|c|C|C|C|c|}
\hline Ableitung des Vielfachen  & c f(x) & c f'(x) \\ 
\hline Quotientenregel & \frac{f(x) }{ g(x)} &  \frac{  f'(x) g(x)  -  f(x) g'(x) }{g(x)^2} \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

How to make the parts of the fraction the same high as the parts above them without the fractions (doubling the rowheight when needed, also not shrinking the fontsize)?

Answer (score 5):

Use `\dfrac` from `amsmath` for this:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lCC}\toprule
        Ableitung des Vielfachen  & c f(x) & c f'(x) \\\midrule
        Quotientenregel & \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} & \dfrac{  f'(x) g(x)  -  f(x) g'(x)}{g(x)^2} \\ % I corrected the math here...
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't except it to be so easy ;) Can I ask for another small improvement please? I need the vertical lines in the table, but if I change \midrule to \hrule and add | in the tabular opening, the space between the fractions and the horizontal lines shrinks to much, any idea on how to solve this too?

Comment: @user2567875, `booktabs` and vertical lines doesn't work (well) together. From aesthetic point of view, vertical lines are not considered as good design ...

Comment: @user2567875 - If you absolutely must have vertical rules (and hence can't use `\toprule`, `\midrule`, etc), take a look at the posting [Inserting a small vertical space in a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50352/5001) and, in particular, the answer that uses typographic struts.

Comment: @user2567875 Bidde bidde. See Zarko's answer for the vertical rules. But I will not give a solution with such. As you can see, `booktabs` provides perfect spacing above and below the math-term. Just great. And the more lines, the less readable. I would even replace `\midrule` by `\addlinespace` but I have not seen the full table...

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I know thats regarded as typograpy-hell, and I would agree in about 90% of the cases. But I need strong visual structure for my brain to be able to memorize it. And since I will write more annotations by hand into the printout later, the "grid" just has to be there to pre-set the structure I need.

Answer (score 1):

If you persist on vertical rules, than (good old) `mdwtab` will give nice result:
[image]

and code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath
\usepackage{mdwtab}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|Mc|Mc|}
\hlx{hv}
        Ableitung des Vielfachen  & c f(x) & c f'(x) \\
\hlx{vhvv}
        Quotientenregel & \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} & \dfrac{  f'(x) g(x)  -  f(x) g'(x)}{g(x)^2} \\ % I corrected the math here...
\hlx{vvh}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @LaRiFaRi :special thanks for the "I corrected the math here..."