# How can you draw a horizontal line inside an align environment?

Tags: align

I need to draw a horizontal line inside an align environment. E.g., in the following MWE, I need that a line separates the third row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
    x &= 1\\
    y & = 2 \\
    \hline
    x + y &= 3 
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT** I forgot to mention, the line should not be too long to the left (notice the attached image).

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
x &= 1\\
y & = 2 \\
 \cline{1-2}
x + y &= 3 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please give an explanation about what `\cline{}` is and what its arguments control.

Comment: This solution puts a tremendous amount of vertical whitespace around the line.

Comment: [This is what I came up with](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/635159/214194).

Answer (score 7):

I've done a lot of research on this problem and this is the simplest
solution from all that I've seen. While [touhami's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254262/214194) is great, I take issue with the vertical spacing.

In order to use things like `\hline` in a math environment, I found you need to be in a an "sub" math environment* like `split`, `aligned`, etc.. Once so, you can use your code unchanged:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
    x &= 1 \\
    y &= 2 \\
    \hline
    x + y &= 3 
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: nonsensical equation]

If you want to include the equation number replace the `equation*` environment with `equation`:

[image: nonsensical equation numbered]

I'm not entirely pleased with the vertical spacing surrounding `\hline`. It could be a bit more with some formulas, but `\hline \\[-.5ex]` is not respected. Feel free to leave a solution in the comments and I'll incorporate it.

Other options to document might include trying to wrangle `\frac{top}{bottom}` to do what you want.

---

*Fortification of this statement welcome! My latex knowledge is limited.

Helpful resource:
[User Guide for amsmath](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf)

## Update [2.27.22]

[I found a clean way to add a bit more space after the `\hline`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/635458/214194)!

```latex
\noalign{\smallskip} \hline \noalign{\smallskip}
```

Which can be stored in a command:

```latex
\newcommand{\eqline}{\noalign{\smallskip} \hline \noalign{\smallskip}}
```

Output:
[image: nonsensical equation with good spacing]

Updated tex:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\eqline}{\noalign{\smallskip} \hline \noalign{\smallskip}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
    x &= 1 \\
    y &= 2 \\
    \eqline{}
    x + y &= 3 
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Not too sophisticated but you could use a simple `rule` here.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        x &= 1\\
        y & = 2 \\[-\jot] % you may decrease the vertical space here and in the next line as well.
        \mathclap{\rule{2cm}{0.4pt}}\\
        x + y &= 3 
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the significance of `\mathclap{}`?

Comment: @young_souvlaki it sets the horizontal part of the bounding box to zero. Like this, the rule does not occupy any space in horizontal direction.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{>{\displaystyle{}}r@{}>{\displaystyle{}}l}
    x &= 1\\
    y & = 2 \\
     \hline
    x + y &= 3 
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

or may be you like the spacing of `booktabs` more

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools,array,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{>{\displaystyle{}}r@{}>{\displaystyle{}}l}
    x &= 1\\
    y & = 2 \\
     \midrule
    x + y &= 3 
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for sake of completeness. In plain TeX, we have no problem.

```
$$
  \eqalign{
        x &= 1 \cr
        y &= 2 \cr \noalign{\smallskip\hrule\smallskip}
    x + y &= 3 
  }
$$    
\bye
```

gives desired result.

Answer (score 0):

By using `\mathclap` in `mathtools` package you have many options, like space between previous and after lines, line height and lenghth.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \begin{eqnarray*}
   x& = 1 \\
   y& = 2 \\[-3mm]
 \hspace{13mm}\mathclap{\rule{6cm}{0.4pt}}\\[-2mm]
   x + y &= 3 
  \end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit the extra value of your answer to @LaRiFaRi's answer?