# adding a horizontal line in align environment in lyx

Tags: equations, lyx, align, alignat

I use the AMS `align` environment to write some algebraic steps which have many lines of equations. I want to add some space (or preferably horizontal) after each line of equation with `=`. How can I do that?

So what I want to achieve is:

```
a = 1x2+3
---------
  = 2+3
---------
  = 5
```

Or other visually pleasing way to separate multiple lines of equations.

Comment: You can manually set the space between lines using the optional Argument of \\. Like \\ [12pt].

Comment: Unfortunately the optional argument of \\ is not supported in LyX (yet?)

Comment: @G.M. perhaps this is the corresponding ticket for lack of optional argument after \\? http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/1505

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Adding horizontal lines in AMS align in LyX**

Use the menu element Edit > Math > Add Line Above/Below. This inserts `\hline` between the desired lines.

However for AMS `align` this produces a line that starts at the left margin, which is probably not what you wish for. The solution is to replace the `align` environment with an `aligned` environment, in which the `\hline` seems to be better behave.

*Detailed instructions*: Create a new display math inset (Ctrl+Shift+M), and inside it type `\aligned`. This creates a `aligned` inset, in which you add as many columns and rows as desired. You can now cut-paste from your `align` environment to your new `aligned` environment. Now, use Edit > Math > Add Line Above/Below to add lines where desired.

Result in the code preview pane:

```
\[
\begin{aligned}a & =1\times2+3\\
\hline  & =2+3\\
\hline  & =5
\end{aligned}
\]
```

**Increase spacing between lines in AMS align**

Define a math macro `\linespacing` with contents `\rule[-#1]{0pt}{0pt}` and use it to increase spacing with the next line.

Result in the code preview pane:

```
\global\long\def\linespacing#1{\rule[-#1]{0pt}{0pt}}
\begin{align*}
a & =1\times2+3\linespacing{2ex}\\
 & =2+3\linespacing{2ex}\\
 & =5
\end{align*}
```

Comment: where is the `add line from above/below`? I can't find 'Math' in Edit. I can only find 'horizontal line' under 'formatting' in 'Insert'. Btw, mine is version 2.2.0

Comment: I manage to add the lines by typing \hline directly. but now the problem is that if I can't number each line. If I right-click and choose 'Equation Label', then it can only label the whole aligned environment and give one equation label, but I want more than one.

Comment: You should also be seeing "Add line from above/below" when right-clicking in a cell. My solution indeed does not work when you need individual row labelling. That was the only caveat I know of. The following suggests a problem in general with horizontal lines in the align environment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254261/how-can-you-draw-a-horizontal-line-inside-an-align-environment. You can try the `\cline{1-2}` solution  (by hand) suggested there but it gives me a poor result.

Comment: then what about having multiple separate align environments aligned to the same '='? This way I can have multiple equation labelling, and also sometimes I want to add some text in between the equations for explanations. But I don't know how to make those separate align environment (with some text in between) aligned to the same '='

Comment: My advice for such a specialised request is to ask the LaTeX people here how to best do this in LaTeX, then see how to this can be adapted to LyX.