# Tables, Cellcolor and horizontal lines

Tags: tables, hhline

I don't understand why my lines aren't showing up or look funny in this minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

 \begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{|cc|p{1in}|cc|p{1in}|cc|} \hhline{--~--~--}
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{green!50!white}U.S.} &&\multicolumn{2}{|c|} 
 {\cellcolor{green!50!white}France}&&\multicolumn{2}{|c|} 
 {\cellcolor{green!50!white}Japan} \\ \hhline{--~--~--}
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$8$} &&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$41\frac{1} 
 {3}$}&&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$260$} \\ %\hhline{--~--~--}
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$9$} &&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$42\frac{2} 
 {3}$}&&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$270$} \\ \hhline{--~--~--}
 \end{tabular}
 \end{center}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your `\hhline` s are empty in  the `p[1in}`columns, so it looks normal, except for a missing vertical line in the first row. What did you expect?

Comment: @Bernhard, why is it missing in row 1 I thought I put that there and what syntax would I use to include in the p{1in} columns?

Comment: The horizontal lines? Use `\hhline{--------}` or `\hhline{*{8}{-}`.

Comment: I am referring to the vertical line missing in the first box? The horizontal lines are okay

Comment: It is not missing when I compile. Maybe a problem with the pdf viewer. What happens when you zoom?

Comment: @Yes I see when I zoom in. Maybe I should adjust the arraywidthrule ? Strange this is happening

Comment: Which viewer do you use?

Comment: pdf adobe Acrobat DC most recent version

Comment: This is common and is viewer-dependent; not an issue with TeX and therefore off-topic.

Comment: i clearly see all lines in sumatra as well in adobe DC recent version (screen resolution is 1920 x 1200).

Comment: I use SumatraPDF, which the recommended viewer (it doesn't lock the .pdf, and understands the .sync files, so you can do direct and inverse search). Also, don't you have holes in some vertical rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It is not clear why you use define columns cor each sub-table and than in them `multicolumn{2}{c}{...}`. It should be sufficient to use just one ...
- For better visibility of vertical rules in colored part of table you can increase thickness of rules. For example to 0.5pt.
- For removing holes in vertical lines use for horizontal lines `\hhline{|-|~|-|~|-|}`
- Vertical space around cells' contets can be increased by use of the `cellspace` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cellspace, hhline}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{2pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{2pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{|Sc|p{1in}|Sc|p{1in}|Sc|}
    \hhline{|-|~|-|~|-|}
\cellcolor{green!50!white}{U.S.} 
    &&  \cellcolor{green!50!white}{France}  
        &&  \cellcolor{green!50!white}{Japan}   \\ 
    \hhline{|-|~|-|~|-|}
$8$ &&  $41\frac{1}{3}$ &&  $260$               \\ %\hhline{-~-~-}
$9$ &&  $42\frac{2}{3}$ &&  $270$               \\ 
    \hhline{|-|~|-|~|-|}
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your lines are visible, but it depends on the PDF viewer you're using. Some viewers snap elements to a grid which could cause some components to be overridden by other things. This is commonly the case when adding colour to tables.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
  \begin{tabular}{ | c | p{1in} | c | p{1in} | c | }
    \hhline{-~-~-}
    \cellcolor{green!50!white}U.S. && \cellcolor{green!50!white}France && \cellcolor{green!50!white}Japan \\
    \hhline{-~-~-}
    $8$ && $41\frac{1}{3}$ && $260$ \\
    $9$ && $42\frac{2}{3}$ && $270$ \\
    \hhline{-~-~-}
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, there is no need for two columns in your setup, since a single column suffices.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account the comments above and @Mico answer here-- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50355/197451-- added strut since the fractions were touching the horizontals

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\T{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}       % Top strut
\newcommand\B{\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % Bottom strut
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{|cc|p{1in}|cc|p{1in}|cc|} \hhline{--~--~--}
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}
 {\cellcolor{green!50!white}U.S.} 
                                &&\multicolumn{2}{|c|} 
                                  {\cellcolor{green!50!white}France}
                                  \T\B
                                                                        &&\multicolumn{2}{|c|} 
                                                                          {\cellcolor{green!50!white}Japan} \\ \hhline{*{8}{-}}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}
 {\cellcolor{blue!20!white}$8$} 
                                &&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}
                                  {\cellcolor{blue!20!white}$41
                                  \frac{1}{3}$} \T\B
                                                                        &&\multicolumn{2}{|c|} 
                                                                          {\cellcolor{blue!20!white}$260$} \\ 
                                                                          \hhline{*{8}{-}}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}
 {\cellcolor{red!10!white}$9$} 
                                &&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}
                                  {\cellcolor{red!10!white}$42
                                  \frac{2}{3}$} \T\B
                                                                        &&\multicolumn{2}{|c|} 
                                                                          {\cellcolor{red!10!white}$270$} \\ 
                                                                          \hhline{*{8}{-}}                                                                          
 \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
```

Answer (score 0):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has been created to address that problem. With this environment, the lines will *not* seem do disappear in some PDF viewers at some levels of zoom (and you will not see the thin white lines you see sometimes in some PDF viewers like SumatraPDF when you use `colortbl` or the key `table` of `xcolor`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
  \begin{NiceTabular}{|c|}[colortbl-like] \hline
    \cellcolor{green!50!white}U.S. \\ \hline
    $8$ \\
    $9$ \\ \hline
  \end{NiceTabular}
  \hspace{1in}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{|c|}[colortbl-like] \hline
    \cellcolor{green!50!white}France \\ \hline
    $41\frac{1}{3}$ \\
    $42\frac{2}{3}$ \\ \hline
  \end{NiceTabular}
  \hspace{1in}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{|c|}[colortbl-like] \hline
    \cellcolor{green!50!white}Japan \\ \hline
    $260$ \\
    $270$ \\ \hline
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]