# How to remove horizontal table lines when using right bracket?

Tags: tables

Here's my mwe. How do I remove all of those horizontal table lines in the last column?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}  

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c||c|c}
\hline 
Config Number & k1 & k2 & Pk &  \\
\hline 
1 & 1 & 0 &  X & \rdelim\}{3}{3mm}[$5\% $] \\ 
\hline 
2 & 1 & 0 &  Y \\ 
\hline 
3 & 1 & 0 & Z \\ 
\hline 
\hline
4 & 1 & 0 & A & \rdelim\}{4}{3mm}[$15\% $] \\ 
\hline 
5 & 1 & 0 & B \\ 
\hline 
6 & 1 & 0 & C\\ 
\hline 
7 & 1 & 0 & D \\ 
\hline 
8 & 1 & 0 & E\\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by replacing your `\hline` with `\cline{1-4}`, which will create a horizontal line spanning columns 1-4:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}  

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c||c|c}
\cline{1-4}
Config Number & k1 & k2 & Pk &  \\
\cline{1-4}
1 & 1 & 0 &  X & \rdelim\}{3}{3mm}[$5\% $] \\ 
\cline{1-4}
2 & 1 & 0 &  Y \\ 
\cline{1-4}
3 & 1 & 0 & Z \\ 
\cline{1-4}
\noalign{\vskip 1mm}    
\cline{1-4}
4 & 1 & 0 & A & \rdelim\}{4}{3mm}[$15\% $] \\ 
\cline{1-4}
5 & 1 & 0 & B \\ 
\cline{1-4}
6 & 1 & 0 & C\\ 
\cline{1-4}
7 & 1 & 0 & D \\ 
\cline{1-4}
8 & 1 & 0 & E\\ 
\cline{1-4} 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where did the vertical space go between config number 3 and 4 (as shown in my example)?

Comment: good question, I didn't notice this. I guess you could insert \noalign{\vskip 1mm} in between the two cline. (This is suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50408/34936)). It's not as nice as the previous vertical space though, as it's not the same height as the width of the horizontal space.