# Spacing in a multirow table

Tags: tables, white-space, vertical-spacing

I am trying to use a multi-row table such that I can have some extra spacing before and after the table's entire header and before and after the first element of the rows. The screenshot is enclosed:

[image]

A working example of the same is as follows:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l}
\hline
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} \\
\hline
\multirow{17}{0.11\textwidth}{A} & B & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}C \\ D\\ E \\ \end{tabular}\\ 
\cline{2-3} 
& X & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} C \\ D\\ E \\ \end{tabular}  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Apologies for my poor knowledge of LaTeX.

Comment: One way is to use `\makegapedcells` defined in the `makecell` package, the another  ways is use `\cellspace` package and define spaces for `\cellspacetoplimit` and  `\cellspacebottomlimit`. Well, your knowing of LaTeX will grow with their use :-), so happy TeXing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking to insert typographic struts in various locations. See the following for an example of how this may be done. The screeshot shows the `tabular` *without* struts on the left and *with* struts on the right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50355/5001
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}       % Top strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % Bottom strut
\newcommand\TBstrut{\Tstrut\Bstrut}         % Top-and-Bottom strut

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
% first, without struts
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{0.11\textwidth}|l|l}
\hline
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{A} & B & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}C \\ D\\ E \\ \end{tabular}\\ 
\cline{2-3} 
& X & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} C \\ D\\ E \\ \end{tabular}  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\qquad
% second, *with* struts
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{0.11\textwidth}|l|l}
\hline
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C}\TBstrut \\ % <-- note the "\TBstrut" directive
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{A} & B & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}C\Tstrut \\ D\\ E\Bstrut \\ \end{tabular}\\ 
\cline{2-3} 
& X & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} C\Tstrut \\ D\\ E\Bstrut \\ \end{tabular}  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mico. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Now I'm not sure, what is your problem. However, based on my comment, in the first I understood that you looking for something like this:

[image]

Above table example is produced by:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering} % if you like to have horizontal 
                                            % centered multirow cells contains
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l}
    \hline
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C}    \\
    \hline
\multirow{5}{0.11\textwidth}{A} 
        & B & \makecell[l]{C \\ D\\ E } \\
    \cline{2-3}
        & X & \makecell[l]{C \\ D\\ E } \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```