# I want to increase the line spacing in the following array table, what should I do?

Tags: tables, math-mode, amsmath, line-spacing, arrays

I want to increase the line spacing in the following array table, what should I do?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb} 
\begin{document}
\[
 \begin{array}
 {|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline
 X & 1 & 2 & 3
 \\
 \hline
 \mathrm{p}(X=x_{i}) &
 \dfrac{1}{22} & \dfrac{9}{22} & \dfrac{6}{11}
 \\
 \hline
 \end{array}
 \]
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to increase the line spacing *per se*, or do you mainly want to get some visual separation between the cell contents and the horizontal rules? Please advise.

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50355/5001) to the query [Inserting a small vertical space in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50352/5001)?

Comment: Do you really need the rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tabularray}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tblr}{cells=c,rowsep=3pt,hlines,vlines}
X & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\operatorname{p}(X=x_{i}) & \dfrac{1}{22} & \dfrac{9}{22} & \dfrac{6}{11} \\
\end{tblr}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]